# INSERT into MySQL 5.x using EXISTS

Tags: mysql, insert

This question has been asked and answered numerous times, but I'm still stumped. All I want to 
do is run an insert statement if a value is not already present in a column. Note, the values in this column do not constitute primary keys, so the `replace` or `update` approach won't work.

`word_id (PK, auto-complete) | word | timestamp (autocomplete)`
`1--sinecure--25th March`
`2--demotic--3rd April`
`3--atavism--5th May`

Before adding another word to this table, I first want to check that it is not already present.
With that in mind, this example should leave the table unchanged.

`INSERT INTO word_table(word) VALUES "sinecure"`
`WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT word FROM word_table WHERE word LIKE "sinecure")`

Of course, the table is unchanged after this query, but only because it throws an error. 
This isn't the only syntax I've tried but it is the one most often advocated on the various 
forums/tutorials I've looked at. I've also had a go at various hacks, for example using variables to store the bool value produced by the EXISTS statement, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
INSERT INTO word_table (word) 
SELECT 'sinecure'
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT word FROM word_table WHERE word LIKE 'sinecure') ;
```

If that behaviour is wanted at all times and not occasionally, add a unique constraint on the `word` column, as others advised. then you can use a simple insert, which will throw an error if the word is duplicate:

```
INSERT INTO word_table (word) 
VALUES ('sinecure') ;
```

or an `INSERT IGNORE` which will ignore errors:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO word_table (word) 
VALUES ('sinecure') ;
```

Comment: +1 That was the trick to overcome this *limitation* in mysql.

Comment: @Augusto There is no MySQL limitation at this. `INSERT INTO table VALUES (...) WHERE ...` is invalid syntax in all SQL dialects.

Comment: Have opted to go down the unique constraint route. Not perfect, because it rules out the existence on homographs within the list, but there aren't many of them so I should get away with it.

Answer (score 2):

If my memory serves me right, you can't do a nested query on the table you want to update. What you can do is to run the select and if you don't get any result, insert the data.

Otherwise, you probably already have an index on the `word` column. Make that index unique and your problem will be solved as the DB will return an error if the word already exists. The word won't be your primary key, but it's in fact an alternate (unique) key.

Answer (score 0):

The field word should have an unique key constraint. Just create the index and you'll have it.